# Is it possible to increase the playback rate (speed up the video) when using Amazon Elastic Transcoder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm looking at speeding up a video before storing it in S3. I haven't found anything on the AWS docs about this.

Is this something that can be done with AWS Elastic Transcoder?

Thanks!
Sébastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Yet.

Thought, You can try writing to their [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=147), asking for this feature...

It sounds like it's the only way to get this kind of functionality exported to API.

Extracted from [faqs](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/faqs/):

> **Q: Why is the codec parameter that I want to change not exposed by the API?**
>
> In designing Amazon Elastic Transcoder, we wanted to create a service that was simple to use. Therefore, we expose the most frequently used codec parameters. If there is a parameter that you require, please let us know by letting us know through our forum.

Aha, apparently, already [did](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=215681&tstart=0) :}

Comment: Aw, not what I wanted to hear, but expected as much :) I'm a bit worried about the level of support on AWS forums though. I will leave the answer open for a bit more time to let others propose solutions.

Comment: I would say, that contacting support [directly](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) You might get lucky... but, it seems, technical support is additional costly feature...